# Transfer Emails from a host to another (Bluehost to Hostgator

Tags: hosting

I want to transfer Email accounts from Bluehost to Hostgator.

I've read everywhere that using a full cPanel backup will do the job.

My question is, can I transfer the mail dir via FTP from a host to another?

If this doesn't work, both of my hosts supports cPanel so any further advice is appreciated.

I Do not have FTP access of the old host, the owner of the previous host is giving me a TAR of the mail dir.

Comment: Questions concerning the use of **shared web hosting by end users or resellers**, rather than the administration of web hosting, are off-topic. These questions should be directed to your web hosting provider's support channels.

Answer (score 3):

You have a *lot* of variables here. In order for your tar plan to work, you're going to need to ensure that the new mail server supports mailboxes in the format you have inside your tarball. To do this, you're going to need to know what mailserver you're using and how to configure it. To do that, you should ditch cPanel - it does things in completely non-standard ways, and obscures the details needed to actually know what is going on with your server, and which are needed to troubleshoot things in the future.

If you still have IMAP access to the old host, using [imapsync](http://imapsync.lamiral.info/) would honestly be the easiest migration path. Doing this, you don't need to worry about mailbox format - the target mailserver will sort that out for you.

Answer (score 2):

Using the IMAP mail protocol, you use your mail client to copy e-mails from hoster to another. If you have a bigger migration project, you can use a cloud-based IMAP migration service.

Comment: Altghough not exactly what I'm looking for, Thanks for this, I'll keep it in mind!

Comment: This might be fine for a single account, but for multiple accounts, using a standard mail client is quite laborious and error-prone.